# PHP: String replace to delete everything except "foo"?

Tags: php, string, text, replace

What function can I use to get this string:

`The random foo wants to be left alone.`

to this:

`foo`

?

*note: foo appears within randomly generated text*

Comment: This question is off-topic because it lacks a minimal research effort. Update your question with what you've tried.

Comment: If there is a "foo" that is.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (strpos(' '.$a.' ',' foo ') !== false) {
    $a = "foo";
}
elseif(strpos(' '.$a.' ',' foo.') !== false) {
    $a = "foo";
}
```

Thanks to the comments, this should work. Would not work if it's last word in sentence and it's closed with "!" or "?" etc. but you could make `elseif` for this, just like the elseif for "."

Comment: What if there is a word called `food` ?

Comment: Good comment, didn't think of that at all.

Comment: spaces either side should fix that

Comment: Yes but that way it won't count if it's the first word

Comment: You need one more thing to be sure it is working...what if 'foo' is on first or right place ? You need to extend ' '.$a.' ' in strpos... strpos(' '.$a.' ',' foo '); (add space before and on end of string, not sure if seen in comment)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this

```
$arr=explode(' ',$string);//OR ANY OTHER DELIMITER
if(in_array($foo,$arr)) $x=$foo;
```